# How to find from xml files using a substring? (Python)

Tags: python, xml

Hello I've been searching for an answer on this for hours and I cannot figure out what I should use if a field contains a substring.

```
for movie in root.findall('.//movie/moviename'):
    if movie.attrib.get('name') == 'Fantastic Beasts':
        result = movie.text
        break
print(result)
```

I want to be able to use this substring to find the value of the record that CONTAINS the substring 'Fantastic Beasts'. In this case the full string of the field movie is:

"Fantastic Beasts And Where To Find Them"

So can I use something else instead of `==` that will search fields with this substring?

Comment: use `in` operator like, `if 'Fantastic Beasts' in movie.attrib.get('name') :`

Comment: @akashkarothiya much appreciated!

Comment: I've removed the XQuery tag and the mention of XQuery in the title, since the question appears to be about Python and to have nothing to do with XQuery.  (If I'm missing something, you might make the XQuery part of the question more explicit.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match substring, then use `in` operator

```
if 'Fantastic Beasts' in movie.attrib.get('name'):
```